# Backbone data logic inside view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am not sure where to perform the action of preparing the data for the template of my view. Currently I have this piece of code.

```
getTemplateData: function () {
        var inventoryStatus = selectedDevice.get("inventoryStatus"),
            data = {},
            statusName,
            inventoryDate;
        statusName = getConfigValue("pdp", "statusMap", inventoryStatus);
        data.message = getConfigValue("pdp", "statusMessage", statusName);
        data.className = "";
        data.dataAttribute = null;
        data.tooltipValue = null;
        data.displayError = false;



        var redirectCode = (allDevices.get("thirdPartyRedirectCode") !== null) ? allDevices.get("thirdPartyRedirectCode") : "";
        if (redirectCode) {
            if (redirectCode === 9999) {
                data.buttonDisabled = false;
                data.buttonText = "Design Yours";
            } else if (redirectCode === 9998) {
                data.buttonDisabled = true;
                data.buttonText = "Design Yours";
            }
            return false;
        }



        switch(inventoryStatus) {
            case 1001: //Out of Stock
                data.buttonDisabled = true;
                data.displayError = true;
                break;
            case 1002: //Pre Order
                data.buttonDisabled = false;
                break;

        }

        return data;
    }
```

This getTemplateData() I call inside my render function of the view. This seems wrong by the looks of it and i am unsure where to place this code.
Should I create different getters in my model or should i leave them inside my main view. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know the "correct" way of doing this is to put it in the model, and in the view have

```
getTemplateData: function () {
    return this.model.getTemplateData();
}
```

**EDIT**

In case of multiple models for a view (which shouldn't happen, without getting into your decisions at the moment) you can have a `getTemplateData` for each, and call them with something like [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
getTemplateData: function () {
    var data = this.model1.getTemplateData();
    data = $.extend(data, this.model2.getTemplateData());
    return data;
}
```

***BUT***
What you really should do, IMHO, is give each it's own view, where one of them is smaller and intended to be included in the other. (i.e. `bigView.$el.append(smallView.el)`)

Comment: The issue that i am facing is that i am combining two different models in this case. Alldevice and selecteddevice

Comment: Try to separate the views (or combine the models). At any rate, see edit

Comment: Also one concern that i had is that should the values be set inside the model for eg: i am setting data.buttonDisabled = false; button disabled is not a part of the model so should i write this statement here or this part goes into the view

Comment: I don't know enough about your project to say if you should rename that our refractor your logic. Try to keep it logical for the next developer - that's usually good practice.